# What (wall) cleaning product ingredients are safe for cats?

Tags: cats, safety

Please give me the names of the ingredients so that I can see what to buy.

I live in the UK, so I need the ingredients, not just a brand-name that may be unavailable here. Thanks.

Comment: What have you researched so far?

Comment: use a natural plant oil based soap like pine-sol https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pine-Sol this is sold worldwide but the brand name might be different depending on where you live.read the warning on the container as no types of soap is 100% safe,it is after all made to disolve fat and kill bacteria.